# Why is WooCommerce shortcode [product_categories] attribute ids not returning anything?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

I was trying to insert the woocommerce shortcode **`[product_categories ids="27"]`** using elementor, the id **`27`** is found from the edit category url e.g. : 
`mysite/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=product_cat&**tag_ID=27`

but the category by the id **`27`** is not displayed.
It is to be noted that this category is nested, that means it is the child of another category.

On the other hand, when I try to insert all of the woocommerce top level categories, it does work but doesn't show the thumbnail image for any of the categories.

So I was thinking is it were an internal issue of woocommerce shortcode or there is some problem with my shortcode?

Reference: [The woocommerce shortcodes documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

Comment: First be sure that you have some products using this product category 27… Then you could also try to use  `[product_category category="27"]` instead.

Comment: tag_ID = 27 exists for sure(in the url), so product category 27 exists, but when I try to use [product_category category="27"] it doesn't return anything.Also product_category will return me the products under that category, but I want the list of specific category thumbnails.

Comment: Because you need to set this category on some products, and then it will display those products…

Comment: I did set this category on some products, [product_category category="27"] is not showing me the products under that category, is the tag_ID also the category ID? because in this case, 27 is an ID  I got from the URL tag_ID, which according to several people over stack overflow is the category id.

Comment: The `category` attribute allows term name, term slug or term Id… So try with the term name may be.

Comment: The `category` attribute can only be used as an attribute of `[product_category]` which will return me the products under that category, but I want category thumbnail of the specified thumbnail which can only be returned via `[product_categories]`.And ids when specified will allow me to return category thumbnail of that ids specified.

Comment: Yes you are right! Just tested and it works for me displaying product category thumbnails.

Comment: But does it work with ids attribute where you put the category id of a nested category ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[product_categories hide_empty="0" ids="27"]`.
Woocommerce doesn't display empty categories by default. So to display empty categories we have to **unset hide_empty**.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that the tag_ID is the product category id.

I have confirmed that this works if you have products in the specific category:

```
[product_categories ids="27"]
```

...and this works even if you don't have any products in the category:

```
[product_categories hide_empty="0" ids="27"]
```

Both of them shows the thumbnail, no matter if it's a sub-category or the top-category.

Your problem lies elsewhere, not in this short-code.